# How to redirect to a file tail of an openshift log?

Tags: openshift, tail

The openshift command

```
 rhc tail -a rentapp
```

works fine.

However

```
rhc tail -a rentapp > xxx
```

is stuck forever

Answer (score 0):

I think it has something to do with detection of standard output in *rhc* utility. Whether it's terminal or not.

All you have to do is to trick *rhc* it has terminal on standard output.

You may try to play with *script* utility, I was quite successful with it now:

```
script -q -e -c "rhc tail -a rentapp" /dev/null > xxx
```